# ASSEMBLY 8086 remove specific line from file

Tags: file, assembly, io, x86-16, emu8086

I am new with assembly,
I am trying to remove spicific line from a text file
For example: remove the third line of the file
I tried alot of stuff but i didn't manage to do it
Can please someone help me?

thanks,
Yam

Comment: You could start by showing us the code that you used to try this. Without it, this question is too broad for us to answer!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Without further information, it is going to be very hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

File is stream of bytes. What is "text file" depends on your definition of task, and encoding used.

If this is school project (emu8086 makes me think so), then you are probably dealing with simple raw ASCII text file, i.e. one byte = one character. Then you have probably DOS new lines (`<EOL>` = "end of line") (two bytes: 13, 10) in the text (if you are skilled, you can also support unix one byte 10 and old-mac one byte 13 line ends, and even mistakes [10, 13] pairs).

So to remove third line you need to open source file, open target file for writing, and copy every byte including second new-line (or finish when `<EOF>` = "end of file" is detected in source file ahead of third line). Then you just keep reading source file until you reach fourth `<EOL>` sequence of bytes, and then you copy remaining bytes from source to target file.

I.e. imagine source file of 5 empty lines, when viewed in hexa viewer you will see these bytes:

```
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A
;           ^^^^^ this is third line content, will be removed
```

After removing third line, the new file will contain these bytes:

```
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A
```

= only 4 empty lines.